# Relationship between $\text{Cov}(x_i^2, e_i^2)$, the asymptotic variance of b under homoscedasticity and heteroscedasticity?

Tags: covariance, heteroscedasticity, asymptotics

I am trying to figure out the relationship between $\text{Cov}(x_i^2, e_i^2), V$ and $V_0$, where:

$V=$ asymptotic variance of $\sqrt{n(\hat{\beta}-β)}$ under heteroskedasticity, and
$V_0=$ asymptotic variance of $\sqrt{n(\hat{\beta}-β)}$ under homoscedasticity

Also, I am given that that the expected value of x squared, E(x_i^2), is equal to one.

From this, I get that:

$V = 1/N ∑〖(x_i^2 \cdot e_i^2)〗$
$V_0=σ^2$

I am certain that this is right. Now, using this I get that

$\text{Cov}(x_i^2, e_i^2) = V - 1/N ∑〖(e_i^2)〗$

Now to get $V_0$ into this equation, by mathematical manipulation, I obtained $1/N ∑〖(e_i^2)〗= V_0$, and thus that $\text{Cov}(x_i^2, e_i^2) = V-V_0$

Is this correct? I am afraid that the substitution of $1/N ∑〖(e_i^2)〗$ for $V_0$ is only possible if I assume homoscedasticity. Is this worry justified? If so, how do I proceed? 
Grateful for a response.

In case anyone has the energy to read this, here is how I derived the above (I apologize for the notation, but I do not know how to change it):

Cov(x_i^2 〖,e〗_i^2 )=E(x_i^2 e_i^2 )-E(x_i^2 )E(e_i^2 )

```
                  =V-E(x_i^2 )E(e_i^2 )

                  =V-E(e_i^2 ),  as E(x_i^2 )=1

                  =V-1/N ∑〖(e_i^2)〗
```

Now,

e_i=y_i-X_i'β ̂ = X_i'β+ε_i-X_i'β ̂=ε_i+X_i'β-X_i'β ̂,

e_i^2=ε_i^2+(β-β ̂ )'X_iX_i'(β-β ̂ )+2ε_i X_i'(β-β ̂ ),

σ ̂^2=1/N ∑(e_i^2 )=1/N ∑(ε_i^2)+(β-β ̂ )'1/N ∑(X_iX_i') (β-β ̂) +2 1/N ∑ε_iX_i'(β-β ̂ )

```
              (1)              (2)                               (3)
```

(2) and (3) converge in probability to zero, as it is assumed that beta-hat is a consistent estimator for beta. (1) converges in probability to σ^2. Therefore,

1/N ∑(e_i^2 ) converges in probability to σ^2

Thus, we have that 
Cov(x_i^2,e_i^2 )=E(x_i^2 e_i^2 )-E(x_i^2 )E(e_i^2 )=V-1/N ∑(e_i^2 ) =V-V0